# When to Plant Avocado

Tags: fruit-trees, seedlings, avocado

My avocado tree is about 4" tall now with big bright green leaves. It is still suspended in water. I've read that I should wait for my seedling to reach 6" in height, cut the leaves off, wait for them to grow back, and then plant it in soil. I don't see it gaining height any more, what should I do?

Should I go ahead and plant it in some potting soil?

Also, my tree looks like there are two trees coming from one pit. Is this normal?

[image: My Avocado Tree]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plant it now in a pot with a height and diameter of four to six inches.  [Avocados are trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado) so in good conditions you can expect that it will need to be re potted one size larger in a year or two.

Avocados exhibit [apical dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_dominance) so when I have cut mine back they do not sprout multiple leaders but just sit there until one new bud one the side forms.  I do not see any value in cutting back a seedling.

Two leaders from one seed means it is very healthy. Likely one will become dominant but you can let nature take it's course.

See [this answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/advanced-care-of-an-indoor-avocado-plant?rq=1) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that the bumpy skinned haas avocados only come from clones of the original tree. Avocados grown from seed will be the normal smooth skinned avocado which does not have the high flavor of the haas.

Comment: This is only partially correct.  It is correct in as much as the resulting fruit will not be a Hass and will likely have very different characteristics, however you can't say more then that with respect of how (or if) the new one will fruit - Not all "non-hass" avocados are smooth skinned - indeed, I'd imagine smooth skin avocados are a minority.