# Why should I prune my avocado plant already when only two weeks old?

Tags: houseplants, pruning, avocado

In most instructions I've read about growing an avocado plant, it says things like the following:

> In 2-6 weeks, roots and a stem will sprout from the seed. When the stem is about six inches long, trim it in half.

What's the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim the roots, yes. This will encourage a denser root system.  Trim the stem? I can't see why.  An avocado is a tree and no amount of trimming on the stem will make it grow like a bush. Avocado's exhibit [apical dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_dominance) although not to the same degree as an evergreen. One stem will be more dominant and grow more than the others.

See these other [questions](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avocado) here for more information about growing avocados and what [they look like](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/3052/499) after they have been potted up for a while.

Comment: The general belief is that stem trimming promotes more branching, possibly a thicker/stronger stem and faster growth but I don't know how scientific this belief is.