# Avocado... help my girl go down the right path!

Tags: avocado

Overall... I'm pretty happy with how she's doing, but I do have some questions!

Here are some pictures of our avocado tree - she was started from a seed from a very mature tree.

Questions:

1. I'm thinking she needs moving into a bigger pot, correct?
2. What are your thoughts on the leaf droop?
3. I've noticed that she's growing straight up without any off-shooting...   (however it looks like toward the top she is off-shooting, but I'm not certain!)... I do know that we never did clip the top when she was younger.  Thoughts?

Any other advice?  We're in SE Florida and I'd like to keep her inside until she is super-strong and ready to fight on her own.

[image: Avocado]

[image: Avocado 2]

Comment: looks like you are doing good to me, planting it in a bigger pot can't hurt... start moving it outside a few hours every day... until it is ready to stay outside

Comment: Would you suggest pruning it at any point or anything else?  Or just put it in a bigger pot?

Comment: What a beautiful plant! She looks healthy!

Comment: Your latest picture looks like sunburn, or possibly a nutrient deficiency.  Are the brown gold areas dry and papery?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of people who like to grow avocado. You are fortunate that you can grow yours outside year round.

- repot with a pot one size larger
- the leaves are drooping in response to reduced sunlight.  Outside the light comes from above and leaves are held parallel to the ground. Inside more light comes from all levels and the leaves respond by changing orientation.
- Avocados are trees. When grown inside they frequently end up [looking spindly](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/3054/499) with just a little puff of leaves at the top.
- another reason to repot is the start of a minor nutrient deficiency that you can see in the first picture on the lower leaves where the veins are bright green and the rest is lighter. Repotting and one application of a fertilizer with magnesium should do the job

The question for you is what do want the plant to be?  As a houseplant an avocado is not a good choice because they want to be trees and are unlikely to flower when grown indoors.

They have been grown outside in Florida [for over 150 years](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/mg213).  If you want to have your own avocado fruit you should plant it outside after getting it used to the higher light levels.

- Unfortunately they do not come true from seed so the quality of the fruit is unknown.
- planting out is done when a tree is two to four feet (~ 1 m) from the top of the soil. Your plant is ready to go!
- select a planting area that does not flood and has full sun
- Many varieties need more than one to be pollinated.  If your neighbours have avocado trees you can probably get by without two plants

These links may assist you:

- [Avocado growing in the Florida home Landscape](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/mg213)
- [Avocado propagation](http://university.uog.edu/cals/people/PUBS/AVOCADO/Mg03900.pdf)

Comment: Ok!  So we've moved her into a new pot... and she seems happy with one exception.  Shortly after moving her to the new pot some of hear leaves have a sort of "copper" or "gold" color in the center.  I'm going to try and snap a picture and post it up.

Comment: http://i99.photobucket.com/albums/l296/funnypete/Mobile%20Uploads/E4D4755D-2D40-45EE-A2E6-C73E5CF66D11.jpg

Comment: http://i99.photobucket.com/albums/l296/funnypete/Mobile%20Uploads/E4D4755D-2D40-45EE-A2E6-C73E5CF66D11.jpg