# Why does my recently transplanted avocado still have droopy, discolored leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, avocado

This avacado tree is about a week old, and now she's looking a little worse than she did [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19307/avocado-help-my-girl-go-down-the-right-path). :(

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I think I'll get the $46 framed print ;-)  You didn't fertilize too much did you? That looks like a burn to me.

Comment: Looks like it went from inside to outside with no acclimatization. My dad does this every year and wonders why the leaves all burn up. He's not a plant guy :-(

Comment: @Stephie - he roasts his geraniums too!

Comment: I never, ever, ever, claimed to have a green thumb. LOL... LOL...

Comment: Ok, actually, we did acclimate it, we put it under the over hang first (less sun) and then eased her into it.  We did a 50/50 blend of planting soil with the other 50% was the soil from our yard (to try and get her "use" to it)...

Any ideas?  Bring her back in, tough it out?  Too much water, not enough water?

Comment: Hi Pete-I edited your question to help others understand what's going on, and the history of the plant. Feel free to rollback if you don't like my edit! I hope she feels better soon!

Answer (score 1):

Drooping leaves can be caused by at least a few things:

1. Transplant shock. Older leaves do not always recover from this drooping, although they may (newer leaves tend to grow in healthy). In my experience the main thing that actually causes transplant shock is probably UV rays shining on plants with disturbed roots. They can have an effect of plants without disturbed roots, too. My reasoning behind thinking that UV rays influence transplant shock so much, in particular, is that the plastic from milk jugs filters the sun in a fashion to where the filtered light does not easily induce wilting/drooping in transplanted plants. Milk jug plastic filters UV rays (it's hard to find clear material that doesn't). It may filter other kinds of light, too, but I don't know of anything else in particular that the jugs filter. I believe the UV index is pretty high in some parts of Florida.
2. Too much chlorine. I've read about this, but I don't know too much about why it can cause wilting. If you use city water, try watering with filtered water and see if your tree likes it.
3. Possibly, too much nitrogen. This is just something I think I remember reading. I don't know if it's true.

So, if you can filter the light, filter the water, and give it some potassium sulfate, that will likely help it perk up. If you give it much potassium, you may need to give it calcium, too, though, but be careful with that. Potassium helps reduce transplant shock.

The discoloration may be caused by a nutrient deficiency. I think maybe potassium or magnesium is what you need. Maybe manganese. I'll have to edit this later and add more information (and verify stuff) and sources. I've got to go, now, though.